# Extracting pageContent of the page returns Blank using Playwright for certain pages

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

```
import {chromium}  from 'playwright'; // Web scraper Library
import * as fs from 'fs';

(async function () {
    const chromeBrowser = await chromium.launch({ headless: true }); // Chromium launch and options
    const context = await chromeBrowser.newContext({ ignoreHTTPSErrors: true ,
        userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36',
      });
    const page = await context.newPage();
    await page.goto("https://jp.abcmouse.com/mkt/privacy/", { waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 60000 });
    let content = await page.content();
    fs.writeFileSync('test.html', content);
    console.log("done")
})();
```

How do we access the Body content of this URL? I am able to extract many webpages but some of them won't work. Is there anything specific to be done for such sites ?

Comment: Blank or incomplete? I got results with your script.

Comment: It seems to be incomplete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page you shared as an example has most of its content inside a shadow root. As the `content` function relies on `document.documentElement.outerHTML` it won't pierce the shadow root. That's why it looks incomplete.

Comment: Thank you . Is there a way in which we can extract the content under shadowroot ?

Comment: Not in a generic way. And if you look at the page there, there are many nested shadow roots. So having the full HTML picture would be quite hard.